# collectionView's didSelectItemAt not called when use it with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uikeyboard

Once I use addGestureRecognizer to dismiss keyboard in scrollView, collectionView's didSelectItemAt would not work. Any suggestions?

UPDATE CODE: Currently I can tap to dismiss keyboard and tap to do something with collection cell. But, if I swipe the scrollView, the keyboard will dismiss. Any way to prevent that?

```
class PostVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var colorCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PostVC.didTapViewForDismissKeyboard))
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapViewGesture)
        tapViewGesture.delegate = self
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool{
        view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    func didTapViewForDismissKeyboard(_ pressed: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("HIHI")
    }

extension PostVC: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement [`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate). Implement its `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` method in your code to return `true` - that way your gesture recognizer will work, but it will also allow other gestures to be recognized (specifically the one in the `collectionView`).

Code:

```
// add this to initializing code to set gesture recognizer's delegate to self
tapViewGesture.delegate = self
```

Delegate implementation:

```
extension YourViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Combine your answer and @duncan answer. I am really close. Please see my update

Comment: does it happen even when you do not use duncan's answer and there is no shouldReceive implementation?

Comment: If I don't use duncan's answer, collectionView still not work

Comment: then is my suggestion helping at all?

Comment: what is the relationship between collectionView and the scrollView? you do know that collectionView extends UIScrollView, thus is effectively a scrollView itself?

Comment: Yes. your answer is helpful. The reason why I still need to handle the swipe( keyboard dismiss) is because I still have two NSNotification for keyboard shown and keyboard hidden, so if swipe dismiss keyboard, some text fields are behind the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a gesture recognizer. That is intercepting your taps and not giving them to the collection view. Instead put your call to `view.endEditing(true)` in the `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` method.

Comment: Wouldn't calling `view.endEditing(true)` in the `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` method do that for you?

Comment: Anyway to dismiss keyboard instead of putting view.endEditing(true) in the collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)?

Comment: Because my collectionview only hold a little space in my view

Comment: I'm not sure if the gesture recognizer will pass the tap on to the view if it fails. You might try setting up a delegate for your gesture recognizer, implementing the `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)` method, and returning false (after calling `view.endEditing(true)`.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I am almost there. Please see my update